# 1mm grid displaying incorrectly (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, mobile, grid

I'm trying to create a grid which shows lines every 1mm and thicker lines ever 10mm and have the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 1,
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    float currentH = 0;
    float currentW = 0;

    int countX = 0;
    int countY = 0;

    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    while (currentW < metrics.widthPixels) {
        if(countX % 10 == 0){
            this.paint.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);
            this.paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GridGreenTens));
        } else {
            this.paint.setStrokeWidth(0.1f);
            this.paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GridGreen));
        }
        canvas.drawLine(currentW, 0, currentW, metrics.heightPixels, paint);
        countX++;
        currentW += px;
    }
    while (currentH < metrics.heightPixels) {
        if(countY % 10 == 0){
            this.paint.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);
            this.paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GridGreenTens));
        } else {
            this.paint.setStrokeWidth(0.1f);
            this.paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GridGreen));
        }
        canvas.drawLine(0, currentH, metrics.widthPixels, currentH, paint);
        countY++;
        currentH += px;
    }
}
```

My problem is that it displays like this:

[image]

As you can see, the thick lines (o.5f) occur much more frequently than they should be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing your colors from shades of green to black or gray as a quick test. On an LCD or other solid state display, a given pixel is made up of multiple R,G,B subpixels. I think that your 1mm line frequency is "beating" with the display frequency, and for some of your lines there is simply no green subpixel available. Note that e.g. (200 dpi / 25.4) / 10 (your 0.1f stroke) is less than a screen pixel wide, even on a tvdpi device.

Comment: In the docs for Paint http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStrokeWidth%28float%29, I also see this comment for setStrokeWidth():
Set the width for stroking. Pass 0 to stroke in hairline mode. Hairlines always draws a single pixel independent of the canvas's matrix.  So, as another quick test, try changing you 0.1f stroke to 0.

Comment: Changing the stroke size to 0 fixed it,  Thank you Yojimbo